# Is feasible to draw a rectangle containing text as a subscript?

Tags: mathjax

I'm trying to make a rectangle containing text as a subscript, something like this

[image]

I tried this code

$x_{\square{i..j}}$

with MathJax and LaTeX

MathJax gives this

[image]

where the subscript `i..j` is not inside the square

while LaTeX gives this

[image]

where the square doesn't render at all.

How do I do it correctly?

PS: it doesn't have to be MathJax

Comment: Remember that `mathjax` is not on topic here as it never uses LaTeX. `\square` is just a symbol and so mathjax gives the proper output. That LaTeX does not render it is simply because you are ignoring compilation errors as `\square` is not defined by default, you'll need something like `amssymb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible in MathJaX to use `\fbox` command to draw a rectangle containing text as a subscript.

Using this code directly `x_{\fbox{i...j}}` you will have

[image]

PS: To compile in MathJaX you can use this link: https://mathjax.github.io/MathJax-a11y/Semantics-Lab/walker/

Comment: Note that \fbox (like any \hbox) reverts to text mode.  `x_\fbox{$\scriptstyle i\dots j}$}` will work in LaTeX.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Hi! Certainly. The question here is MathJaX and not LaTeX.

Comment: I tryed this $x_{\fbox{i...j}}$ in Latex. It works.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro Hi :-). It is sure that it works :-)